# Are spammers attacking the website?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, spam-handling

[This time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284801/online-dating-websites-who-would-consider-them) two unregistered accounts with successive user numbers are the ones. One posts a question while the others posts seconds later with the spam answer solicited by the off-topic question. Deleting their accounts isn't stopping the spam. I flagged but I think everyone should be on alert for this attacks.

Comment: Am guessing this are FUD users from Microsoft trying to create chaos before the awesome power of 13.04 comes out. Anyway, users gone now.

Answer (score 9):

Spammers are attacking *every* website. That's what spammers do; they spam.

Just flag the posts you find. If enough people flag the system will take care of things automagically. Otherwise a moderator will nuke the post when we see your flag.

We don't need a Meta post about every instance :p